# Serializing QHash to QByteArray

Tags: qt, serialization, qt4, tcp, udp

I am trying to serialize a QHash object and store it in a QByteArray (to be sent using QUDPSocket or QTCPSocket).

My current attempt looks like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QHash>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QHash<QString,QVariant> hash;
    hash.insert("Key1",1);
    hash.insert("Key2","thing2");

    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    ds << hash;
    qDebug() << ds;

}
```

When this runs I get this out of `qDebug()`:

```
QIODevice::read: WriteOnly device
QIODevice::read: WriteOnly device
QIODevice::read: WriteOnly device
QVariant(, )
```

The [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdatastream.html#QDataStream-4) says that this should write to the byte array, but obviously that isn't happening here.  What am I doing wrong?

Qt 4.7.1 on OS-X

Thanks!
-J

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine on my machine. I'm on Windows 7 using Qt 4.7.1.

Comment: Your code looks good and works for me.  When dealing with sockets it can be slightly different.

Can you post more code?  If you are having problems with just a main.cpp and that code then its probably something with your setup.

Comment: I updated with the code I am using to work this out.  The warning about reading a write only is only available if `ds` is sent to debug, e.g. `qDebug() << ds;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is failing is because it is trying to read from a write-only stream. The sequence is:

```
qDebug() << ds;
--> QVariant::QVariant(QDataStream &s)
  --> QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &s, QVariant &p)
   --> void QVariant::load(QDataStream &s)
```

That last method (and some more downstream) try to read from the data stream  to convert its contents into a `QVariant` for display in `qDebug`. In other words, your actual code is fine; the debugging check is causing the failure.

You could check the contents of the byte array with something like:

```
qDebug() << ba.length() << ba.toHex();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Implement you program like this code:

```
QHash<QString,QVariant> options;
options["string"] = "my string";
options["bool"] = true;

QByteArray ar;

//Serializing
QDataStream out(&ar,QIODevice::WriteOnly);   // write the data
out << options;

//setting a new value
options["string"] = "new string";

//Deserializing
// read the data serialized from the file
QDataStream in(&ar,QIODevice::ReadOnly);   
in >> options;

qDebug() << "value: " << options.value("string");
```

[ref](http://qt.onyou.ch/2010/10/19/62/)